# Behaviour of `ToExpression` inside a function definition

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, toexpression

I want to create a function that takes in an array of unknown size and do some index operations on it. I am using strings to construct the expression and then trying to use `ToExpression` for evaluating it. But this is not working as I think it should, below is a minimum working example:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
f[arr_] := ToExpression["arr[[1,1]]"];
f[a]
```

This gives an error:

```
Part::partd: Part specification arr[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object.
```

Why is `arr` not in the scope of the function body when `ToExpression` is called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because "arr" inside string do not bind to the input argument. You have to do it separatly.

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
f[arr_] := ToExpression[ToString[arr] <> "[[1,1]]"]
```

And now it works

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this type of coding can easily lead to errors and is fragile. It is better to find different approach for what you are trying to do.

> takes in an array of unknown size

There is a command in Mathematica to find the size of list, it is called [Dimensions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html) and this way the called function can find the size of the input.